# JSTL ForEachTag contains no methods named setVar

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

**Situation**: 
Making an simple exercice, reading countries from a bidimensional array.

**Objective**:
Loop a String[ ][ ] in JSP file, and print its content.

**Problem:**

```
Type org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag contains no methods named setVar.
    <c:forEach items="${array}" var="country">
                                    ^-------^
```

**Tests**:
I saw a few examples from Stackoverflow and around the net, and all have the same syntax. Don't know what's going on.

**Code:**

```
<%@ page import="service.CountryFinderSoapBindingStub"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>    
<%@ page import="java.net.URL" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        CountryFinderSoapBindingStub c = new CountryFinderSoapBindingStub(new URL("http://localhost:7001/World_Countries/services/CountryFinder"),null);
        String[][] array = c.findAllCountries();
    %>
    The Countries are:
    <br>
    <c:forEach items="${array}" var="country">
        <p>City: <c:out value="${array[country][0]}"></c:out></p> <br> 
        <p>Country: <c:out value="${array[country][1]}"></c:out></p>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Changed the jstl-1.2.jar for another more heavy (405KB). It seems I downloaded something older.